# Searching for file in bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage

we are using GCS to store print files that we send to a remote printer. Ideally, we would love to be able to quickly search for files in our GCS bucket like we do on Windows. For example:

"24x18 little lamb striped blue"

This returns a file in Windows, even with typing an inexact match, for example:

24x18 mary had a little lamb striped background blue text.jpg

In GCS it looks like I have to select the filter "Name contains:" and then enter:

24x18
little lamb
striped
blue

Each of those terms needs to be separate. It's a bit time-consuming relative to a native Windows search, is there a way to get the bucket search working in a different way? We perform many of these searches daily, so it would be a huge help if we could get this sorted out.

Thanks!

EDIT: I do realize another option is to search:

"24x18*little lamb*striped*blue"

I guess we are just looking to replicate the searches across platforms so files are uniformly found either locally or on GCS.

Answer (score 0):

What Windows search do? Windows search scans your files in your computer and index them. This means, it creates an entry in its own database with the file information (name, date, type, size,...).

If you want a similar feature on GCS, you need to create your own database, with full text search capacity. Use MongoDB or ElasticSearch for that, maybe PostGreSQL but I'm not sure, and the addon has to be available on Cloud SQL (not sure again).

Anyway, there is no native feature to index the GCS file and to quick find them, you need to implement this mechanism on your side.